# IE6: Large File Uploads fail and a Page Cannot be displayed is returned?

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a very simple file upload PHP script. I am testing with a 175Mb file at the moment. This works fine on all browsers (firefox, chomre etc) including IE7 and above but it does not work for IE6.

When I upload the file, the script should export an access database (that was just uploaded) and all its tables to text files this works great on all browsers but on IE6 the file is uploaded and the script **does export but** IE6 comes back with Page cannot be displayed!

When I upload a small file of about 1MB it works fine, it exports and shows page with results. So I am guessing the time it takes to process is the problem. I have made sure that these are set like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_input_time = 600
```

I also use `set_time_limit(0)` at the top if my script. For apache:

```
Timeout 3000
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

What is the problem? I can't narrow it down any further!

Thanks all for any help on this.

### Update

I should of checked my logs. There are errors, they are similar to this:

```
[29-Jun-2010 14:03:41] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: access_db in
```

All my POST and FILES data is missing! IE6 does not send this across for some reason for large files!!

I wonder why?

### Update 2

Another strange thing to add to the pot: Sometimes IE6 shows a blank page which is when the above errors occur and sometimes it shows the "Page cannot be displayed" and it doesn't get those errors. Wtf is going?!

Comment: What does your receiving script do after handling the files?

Comment: do you get any error, set the error reporting on.

Comment: @Pekka - a simple HTML should be produced by the script, by using simple echos of strings and HTML elements surrounding them. @sAc - I have checked the logs and there are errors. It shows POST/FILES arrays are not populated meaning IE6 is failing to pass this to my script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that setting the `post_max_size` above 2000MB makes IE6 forget or discard the REQUEST variables. I have reduced the `post_max_size` to 1800MB and everything works for me fine  now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be time to move on from IE6, as sites such as YouTube are now not supporting it.